# How can I provide and Inject a DividerItemDecoration in Dependency Injection and should I inject everything?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I believe that I should inject everything. (So we can discuss it also) 
I used a recycleview and added a dividerItemDecoration or LinearLayoutManager

so in my ActivityModule.java

```
public class ActivityModule {

    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

 @Provides
    DividerItemDecoration provideDividerItemDecoration() {
        return new DividerItemDecoration(mActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    }}
```

I provide my DividerItemDecoration like that.

and on **my fragment** I just inject

```
  @Inject
    DividerItemDecoration itemDecorator;
```

and use it like :

```
itemDecorator.setDrawable(Objects.requireNonNull(getDrawable(getBaseActivity(), R.drawable.language_separator)));
```

It is okay for a fragment.

**PROBLEM :**

I can use DividerItemDecoration next time in another fragment  as Horizontal.. and I can not provide DividerItemDecoration again again.

I want to create general method or something . I will inject to my fragment for example

```
@Inject 
DividerItemDecoration itemDecorator(horizontal???).. ?
```

I do not know how its syntax and logic.

**How to provide and inject that kind of codes?**

Waiting your supports.

Also it is a native view stuff, Maybe It can not need to inject.. Please tell your opinions.. I remind you that  still I need an example and to learn for that kind of methods injection and providing..

Thanks a lot

Comment: It makes sense to inject it if you want to provide a different implementation. If not, no point to inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to share a text about Dependency Injection, It makes us to change our mind using dependency injection :

***Do not (always) use DI: Injectables versus newables***

> Something that was immensely useful to me when learning about DI
>   frameworks was the realisation that using a DI framework does not mean
>   that you have to DI to initialise all of your objects. As a rule of
>   thumb: inject objects that you know of at compile time and that have
>   static relations to other objects; do not inject runtime information.
>
> I think this is a good post on the subject. It introduces the concept
>   of 'newables' and 'injectables'.
>
> Injectables are the classes near the root of your DI graph. Instances
>   of these classes are the kind of objects that you expect your DI
>   framework to provide and inject. Manager- or service-type objects are
>   typical examples of injectables. Newables are objects at the fringes
>   of your DI graph, or that are not even really part of your DI graph at
>   all. Integer, Address etc. are examples of newables. Broadly speaking,
>   newables are passive objects, and there is no point in injecting or
>   mocking them. They typically contain the "data" that is in your
>   application and that is only available at runtime (e.g. your address).
>   Newables should not keep references to injectables or vice versa
>   (something the author of the post refers to as
>   "injectable/newable-separation").
>
> In reality, I have found that it is not always easy or possible to
>   make a clear distinction between injectables and newables. Still, I
>   think that they are nice concepts to use as part of your thinking
>   process. Definitely think twice before adding yet another factory to
>   your project!

**We decied to remove injection of ArrayList, LinearLayoutManager, DividerItemDecoration. We created these classes with "new" not inject**

Answer (score 0):

We can inject same class with @Named

```
@Provides
        @Named(CMS.Client.DELIVERY_API_CLIENT)
        fun provideCMSClient(): CDAClient {
            return CDAClient.builder()
                    .setSpace("4454")
                    .setToken("777")
                    .build()
        }



    @Provides
    @Named(CMS.Client.SYNC_API_CLIENT)
    fun provideCMSSyncClient(): CDAClient {
        return CDAClient.builder()
                .setSpace("1234")
                .setToken("456"))
                .build()
    }
```